# Wget and Canadiana

Tags: wget, archive

I'm trying to download this image/archival document http://heritage.canadiana.ca/view/oocihm.lac_reel_c400/1?r=0&s=1 using wget in Command Prompt (Windows 10), but keep getting errors.

```
wget -r -A jpeg, http://heritage.canadiana.ca/view/oocihm.lac_reel_c400/1?r=0&s=1
```

Any clues?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, error was the wrong word. It downloads a file, but not a JPEG. When I try opening the file with a program like Paint, or Windows Photo Viewer, I get an error message saying the program cannot read the file.